# How to render variable from node.js server without have to reload and without using EJS/AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, node.js, socket.io

I have tried using ejs:

node.js:

```
var example = 0;
app.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/public/index.ejs");
  res.render(__dirname + "/public/index.ejs", {example:example});
});
```

index.ejs:

```
<p><%- example %></p>
```

But if the variable has been changed I needed to reload the page to update the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could just use polling (the website reloads all x seconds):

```
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3">
</head>
<body>
 <p><%- example %></p>
</body>
```

Comment: What I wanted is not to reload because this is deleting all the client data, and that slows the website, it's better render only the element that I need instead of the whole page.